# Springfox: @ResponseHeader in @ApiResponse does not render in Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I have Springfox annotations in the code as follows:

```
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Options for the endpoint", responseHeaders = {@ResponseHeader(name = "Allow", description = "Verbs allowed")})})
```

However, the header is not being rendered below the response In Swagger UI.

If I add global response (for internal server error) through Docket, its header renders just fine.

[image]

Is this a misconfiguration or what is a problem here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My problem was that annotation parameter "response" was not set to String.class. It defaults to Void.class and does not render with it.

Corrected code is:

```
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Options for the endpoint", responseHeaders = {@ResponseHeader(name = "Allow", description = "Verbs allowed", response = String.class)})})
```

Comment: Thanks for digging.  That doesn't seem like a very sensible default...